# Cannot assess a global String variable outside OnCompleteListener of FirebaseFirestore's DocumentReference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve the data from my Firebase Firestore as an authenticated user (as per the defined rules) and I am also able to retrieve the same,

But when I am storing the data in a Global string then the string variable only contains it within the scope of Listener function and outside the function, it gives a **NullPointerException**.

For understand it, I toasted the variables inside as well as outside the function. The toast within the Listener displays the data but the toast outside the listener returns `"null null"`.

> Announcement.java

```
public class Announcement extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore db;
String header[],body[];
ArrayList<String> data;
Map<String, Object> data2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_announcement);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    header=new String[4];
    body=new String[4];


    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Announcements").document("1");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.d("", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    header[1] = document.getString("Header1");
                    header[2] = document.getString("Header2");
                    header[3] = document.getString("Header3");
                    body[1] = document.getString("Body1");
                    body[2] = document.getString("Body2");
                    body[3] = document.getString("Body3");
                    Toast.makeText(Announcement.this, header[1]+" "+body[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("", "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("", "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

     Toast.makeText(this, header[1]+" "+body[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: `get()` is asynchronous.  It returns immediately, and the results of the query are delivered to your `onComplete` callback some unknown amount of time later.  You should only use the results of the query inside the callback.

Comment: Any other way to get it outside the callback ?

Comment: Get it *after* the callback occurs.  Location doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why do you have this behaviour and how can you solve this using a custom callback.